# PHP string variable that contains variables does not evaluate

Tags: php, string, variables, eval

I am stuck on something in PHP

```
    $l = $par['Length'];
    $w = $par['Width'];
    $d = $par['Depth'];
    $length = $par['Expr_1'];
    $width = $par['Expr_2'];
```

`$par` is an array read from a database.
Length, Width, Depth are numbers
Expr_1 & Expr_2  are formulas stored as strings
ie something like this:

```
($l + .0625) * ($w + .125) * ($l + .125) * ($w + .0625) + 1.625
```

What should happen is that `$l` `$w` should substitute with the values. If I `echo $l,$w,$d` independently they have the right values. If I `echo $length or $width` it shows the formula.

Even when I try `eval("$width = {$par['Expr_2']};");` it doesn't force it to calculate instead of just read the formula. I know the formula is right because if I manually stick it into `$length` or `$width` it works fine.

Comment: 1. It is bad to use `eval`. 2. If you still want to use it, make sure it is enabled from php.ini.

Comment: 1. don't care as that portion of the database that provides the formulas will be read only so not worried about dangerous code as I check the imputed variables. 2. I just looked through the full php.ini and didn't see anything about enabling or disabling eval. please specify where I should be looking

Answer (score 1):

Variable interpolation into strings only happens when those strings are evaluated source code. When they're just values stored in variables, assignments don't do interpolation.

---

Better would be to store a simple parseable format that doesn't require full-blown `eval()`. Here's some code that can store a format that looks like this:

```
L,0.5;W,0.2;D,0.3:4.7
```

which would be equivalent to `(L+0.5)*(W+0.2)*(D+0.3)+4.7`:

```
$eqn_parts = explode(':', $input);
$add_part = $eqn_parts[1];
$mult_parts = explode(';', $eqn_parts[0]);

$accum = 1;
foreach($mult_parts as $part) {
    $bits = explode(',', $part);
    switch($bits[0]) {
        case "L":
            $accum *= ($length + (int)$bits[1]); break;
        case "W":
            $accum *= ($width + (int)$bits[1]); break;
        case "D":
            $accum *= ($depth + (int)$bits[1]); break;
    }
}
$accum += (int)$add_part;
```

Comment: so how do I fix? I need to store 50+ formulas and the user needs to enter the lxwxd to be converted to a lxw

Comment: Consider storing the equation in a way that you can parse and evaluate instead - for instance, store `(L+0.5)*(W+0.25)+0.3` as `L,0.5;W,0.25:0.3` (Which would then be interpreted as "split on the `:`, take everything before the colon and split it on `;`s, each of those items is a comma-separated pair of an input type and an added constant. Take those, multiply them together, then add the constant after the colon.)

Comment: so there is no way to force php to evaluate it as source code? Did I have the eval command wrong?

Comment: I am confused because if you do $a = 5; $b = 6; $c=$a +$b; $c would evaluate as 11. is $c not a string before the values of $a and $b are declared. Sorry had to edit b/c it is 2am here and I was confused

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `eval` for the formulas... there is the possible option of using something like `preg_replace()` instead... to just replace those formula variables coming from the database... and then converting/typecasting the replaced result to an `(int)` or whatever data type you need this to be.  Then computing the formula from there.  Though... it might not be as reliable as `eval`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: wouldn't I just have the same problem? would php evaluate it at that point?

Comment: I think @Amber's way of storing the formulas in the database would work better.  This is just another way to look at the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Although amber's solution would have worked, I wanted to keep it simple and make all the work I did entering the formulas into the db not a waste. I simply combined $length / $width at the beginning of the string and : at the end and eval'd it.

Thanks, everyone

EDIT to add code that I used:

```
 $l = $par['Length'];
    $w = $par['Width'];
    $d = $par['Depth'];
    $par['Expr_1'] = '$length='.$par['Expr_1'].';';
    eval($par['Expr_1']);
    $par['Expr_2'] = '$width='.$par['Expr_2'].';';
    eval($par['Expr_2']);
```

Comment: Edit your question instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will not be passing "any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand."

The following seems to work well.

```
$width = $par['Expr_2'];
eval('$width = '.$width .';');
```